# Can we say: $ -(\lambda - \delta) \cdot a^2 - \delta \cdot \mu \cdot b^2 + \delta \cdot \nu \cdot a\cdot b \leq -c \cdot (a^2+b^2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For real constants $\lambda , \mu , \nu, \delta > 0$ and real $a, b \geq 0$ is it possible to do the following estimate: $\delta > 0$ can be chosen small enough so that it exists a constant $c > 0$ only depending on $\lambda , \mu , \nu, \delta > 0$ with
$$ -(\lambda - \delta) \cdot a^2 - \delta \cdot \mu \cdot b^2 + \delta \cdot \nu \cdot a\cdot b \leq -c \cdot (a^2+b^2)?$$
And can that $c > 0$ be contructed explicitly?

My idea:
I think this should be "heuristically" possible because for passing the limit $\delta \to 0:$ we get $$ -\lambda \cdot a^2 \leq -c \cdot (a^2+b^2), $$ which is true if we choose $c$ small enough so that
$ \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2 \geq \frac{c}{\lambda-c}$ holds.

Actually it is possible to get the strict inequality by choosing $c$ small enough:
$$ -\lambda \cdot a^2 < -c \cdot (a^2+b^2). $$
From here we get by choosing $\delta > 0$ small enough the desired inequality.
But what would be an approach to get $\delta$ and $c$ explicitly with an easy expression?

Would be grateful for hints!

Comment: I didn't downvote the post but I assume that after $12$ questions you should know that you must show some effort, which isn't done in your post (yet).

Comment: I assume $\kappa$ in the inequality is supposed to be $\nu$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint. It was a typo.

Comment: To clarify, you want to be able to determine $c$ as a function of $\lambda , \mu , \nu, \delta$ that satisfies the inequality for any choice of $a,b$ ? Then find the smallest $\delta$ that allows such a $c$ to exist?

Comment: From $-\lambda \cdot a^2 \leq -c \cdot (a^2+b^2)$ or $c \le \frac{\lambda a^2}{a^2 + b^2}$, when $a \to 0$ and $b$ fixed, we have $\frac{\lambda a^2}{a^2 + b^2} \to 0$.

Comment: Yes, correct. I want do determine $c$ as a function of $\lambda, \mu, \nu, \delta$ so that the inequality is fulfilled for any choice of $a,b.$ I would rather say the greatest $\delta.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two conditions on $c$:
$$
c > 0 \\
-(\lambda - \delta) \cdot a^2 - \delta \cdot \mu \cdot b^2 + \delta \cdot \nu \cdot a\cdot b \leq -c \cdot (a^2+b^2) \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$

We can combine them into bounds on $c$ as follows. $a^2+b^2 > 0$ unless $a=0, b=0$, in which case the the only constraint on $c$ is $c>0$ (which is a trivial case).
$$0 < c \leq \frac{(\lambda - \delta) \cdot a^2 + \delta \cdot \mu \cdot b^2 - \delta \cdot \nu \cdot a\cdot b}{a^2+b^2}$$

The ratio form allows us to define $r \equiv \frac{a}{b}$ to reduce one variable in the expression,
$$0 < c \leq \frac{(\lambda - \delta) \cdot r^2 - \delta \cdot \nu \cdot r + \delta \cdot \mu}{r^2+1}$$

For $c$ to exist, the R.H.S. should be $>0$. That means the numerator should $>0$ (since denominator is always $>0$). I'm ignoring the edges cases where $a=0$ or $b=0$. To ensure this independent of $a,b$, we need
$$(\lambda - \delta) \cdot r^2 - \delta \cdot \nu \cdot r + \delta \cdot \mu > 0 \quad \forall \; r$$

Since this is a quadratic in $r$, we just need to set the discriminant to be negative (since $r$ cannot be negative, theoretically we can have a looser condition, but this is easier for calculation)
$$\delta \cdot \mu > 0 \qquad \text{AND} \qquad \delta^2\nu^2 - 4(\lambda - \delta)\delta\nu \leq 0$$

First condition is satisfied by definition. Second simplifies to,
$$\delta \leq \lambda \left(\frac{4\mu}{\nu^2 + 4\mu}\right) < \lambda \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

So as long as you choose $\delta$ that satisfies the above (which you should always be able to do for any choice of $\lambda, \mu, \nu$), there exists $c$ that satisfies Eq \eqref{eq1}. Now to choose a $c$ that works for any $a,b$,
$$\min_{r \geq 0} f(r), \quad f(r) \equiv \frac{(\lambda - \delta) \cdot r^2 - \delta \cdot \nu \cdot r + \delta \cdot \mu}{r^2+1}$$

You can solve for the minimum by differentiating $f$ w.r.t $r$, setting derivative to $0$, solving to get two roots
$$r' = \frac{-(\lambda - \delta - \delta\mu) + \sqrt{(\lambda - \delta - \delta\mu)^2 + 4\delta^2\nu^2}}{\delta\nu} \\ r'' = \frac{-(\lambda - \delta - \delta\mu) - \sqrt{(\lambda - \delta - \delta\mu)^2 + 4\delta^2\nu^2}}{\delta\nu}$$

Here is where I stop because it's getting tedious. Next steps are to determine which of $r',r''$ are $\geq 0$ using Eq. \eqref{eq2}. Then the $c$ you want is the minimum of $f(0), f(\infty)$ and $f(r'), f(r'')$ for the roots that are $\geq 0$.
$$
f(0) = \delta \cdot \mu, \quad f(\infty) = \lambda - \delta
$$

Note that Eq. \eqref{eq2} enforces $\delta < \lambda$.